# Python Classes: update value of instance when it's called on

Tags: python, class, datetime

I'm playing around with classes, and have created one to time parts of my script.

```
import datetime


class Timer(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.TimeElapsed = self.timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), self.StartTime)

    def hms_string(self, sec_elapsed):
        h = int(sec_elapsed / (60 * 60))
        m = int((sec_elapsed % (60 * 60)) / 60)
        s = sec_elapsed % 60
        return "{}:{:>02}:{:>05.2f}".format(h, m, s)

    def timedif(self, end_datetime, start_datetime):
        seconds_elapsed = (end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds()
        return self.hms_string(seconds_elapsed)
```

What I would like for it to do is to print the amount of time that has elapsed since `StartTime` whenever `Timer.TimeElapsed` is instantiated. Of course, what it does is print `00:00:00`.

How can I modify my class so that when I call on `Timer.TimeElapsed` it uses the actual current time to compare to `StartTime` instead of the time the class was called?

Comment: Why don't you make a `time_elapsed` method (note: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that calculates the difference whenever it's called?

Comment: @jonrsharpe just tried it; seems to be doing the same thing.

Comment: That seems unlikely, but without a [mcve] it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a method instead:

```
import datetime
import time

class Timer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.TimeElapsed = self.timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), self.StartTime)

    def hms_string(self, sec_elapsed):
        h = int(sec_elapsed / (60 * 60))
        m = int((sec_elapsed % (60 * 60)) / 60)
        s = sec_elapsed % 60
        return "{}:{:>02}:{:>05.2f}".format(h, m, s)

    def timedif(self, end_datetime, start_datetime):
        seconds_elapsed = (end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds()
        return self.hms_string(seconds_elapsed)

    def time_elapsed(self):
        return self.timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), self.StartTime)

t = Timer()
print "time elapsed from variable: {}".format(t.TimeElapsed)
time.sleep(1)
print "time elapsed from variable: {}".format(t.TimeElapsed)

t = Timer()
print "time elapsed from method: {}".format(t.time_elapsed())
time.sleep(1)
print "time elapsed from method: {}".format(t.time_elapsed())
```

output:

```
time elapsed from variable: 0:00:00.00
time elapsed from variable: 0:00:00.00
time elapsed from method: 0:00:00.00
time elapsed from method: 0:00:01.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `TimeElapsed` with a `@property`:

```
@property
def TimeElapsed(self):
    return self.timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), self.StartTime)
```

Don't forget to remove `self.TimeElapsed` from your `__init__` method.

Also note that variables and method names shouldn't be in CamelCase according to pep8. Your new property would be named `time_elapsed`.

Answer (score -1):

When you reference Timer.TimeElapsed you are referencing a class attribute that's created at class instantiation time.